# Split multi column semicolon separated string and create records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which receives three string parameters

```
1. p_ReqIDs VARCHAR2
2. p_ItemIDs VARCHAR2
3. p_Qtys    VARCHAR2
```

The above 3 string variables contain semicolon-separated values like this:

```
p_ReqIDs  := "56;56;56;"  
p_ItemIDs := "3;2;1;"  
p_Qtys    := "400;300;200;"
```

I need to split values and create rows like this:

```
p_ReqIDs   p_ItemIDs   p_Qtys  
------------------------------------
  56           3       400  
  56           2       300  
  56           1       200
```

I need the query which splits and insert into table also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could process parameters as follows:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type l_rec_type is record(
  3      r_ReqIDs  varchar2(31),
  4      r_ItemIDs varchar2(31),
  5      r_Qtys    varchar2(31)
  6    );
  7  
  8    type l_rec_list is table of l_rec_type;
  9    -- your parameters. 
 10    l_ReqIDs  constant varchar2(31) := '56;56;56;';
 11    l_ItemIDs constant varchar2(31) := '3;2;1;';
 12    l_Qtys    constant varchar2(31) := '400;300;200;';
 13  
 14    l_rec l_rec_list;
 15  begin
 16  
 17  with Parameters(param) as(
 18      select l_ReqIDs  from dual union all
 19      select l_ItemIDs from dual union all
 20      select l_Qtys    from dual
 21    ),
 22    Occurrences(oc) as(
 23      select level
 24        from ( select max(regexp_count(param, '[^;]+')) moc
 25                 from parameters) s
 26     connect by level <= s.moc
 27    )
 28  select max(res1)
 29       , max(res2)
 30       , max(res3)
 31    bulk collect into l_rec
 32    from (select decode(param, l_ReqIDs, res) res1
 33               , decode(param, l_ItemIDs,res) res2
 34               , decode(param, l_Qtys,   res) res3
 35               , rn
 36            from ( select param, regexp_substr(param, '[^;]+', 1, o.oc) res
 37                        , row_number() over(partition by param order by param) rn
 38                     from parameters p
 39                    cross join occurrences o
 40                  )
 41          )
 42  group by rn;
 43  
 44    for i in l_rec.first..l_rec.last
 45    loop
 46       dbms_output.put_line(l_rec(i).r_ReqIDs || '  ' || l_rec(i).r_ItemIDs || '  ' || l_rec(i).r_Qtys);
 47    end loop;
 48  end;
 49  /



56   2   200
56   1   300
56   3   400

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

If you need to just insert processed data into a table the only `insert into` statement and query will be needed (`bulk collect into l_rec` must be removed):

```
insert into your_table(<<columns>>)
  with Parameters(param) as(
     select l_ReqIDs  from dual union all
     select l_ItemIDs from dual union all
     select l_Qtys    from dual
  .... 
  -- the rest of the query from the above pl/sql block.
```

You also can insert  an entire record into a table(in a case you need to do extra processing of extracted elements before insertion) as follows:

- If number of columns in a table equal to number of elements being inserted

  ```
  for i in l_rec.first..l_rec.last
  loop
     insert into your_table
       values l_rec(i);
  end loop;
  ```
- If number of columns in a table is greater then the number of values being inserted

  ```
  for i in l_rec.first..l_rec.last
  loop
     insert into (select column1, .. ,columnn from your_table)
       values l_rec(i);
  end loop;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

i did like this :) short and sweet.

```
create or replace procedure proc1(p_ReqID varchar2,p_ItemID varchar2,p_ItemQty varchar2)
is
begin
 insert into test(req_id,item_id,itemqty)
 select regexp_substr(req_id,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(item_id,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(item_qty,'[^;]+',1,level)
  from  (
      select p_ReqID Req_ID,p_ItemID item_id,p_ItemQty item_qty
      from dual
      )
  connect by regexp_substr(req_id,'[^;]+',1,level) is not null;
end;
```

Comment: Yes that's shorter. You only need to add `OR` conditions in the `connect by` clause for every parameter in a case if second or third and so on parameter has more elements then first one has. Otherwise you can lose valuable information :)

Comment: Nicholas in my case it would never happen as i am pulling detail records of the same REQ_ID and passing to the .NET webservice for oracle. so all the columns will have equal values ALWAYS :)